# Script for different distributions

Tags: linux, perl, bash

first time here for me, I'm a newbe and I'm sorry for my poor english & my errors :)

I need to write a setup script using perl (or bash) but I get stuck on finding a way to make it running in different linux distros. In particular, this script should install httpd and mysql if they are not already installed. I can use lots of if-else but I wonder if exist any automated system that could do it for me even if I couldn't find anything. Example:

pseudo code

```
//find httpd if is installed, if not it will try to install
try(service httpd status) ..
else try (service apache2 status)
if (not_installed) { 
   try yum install httpd
   else try apt-get install apache2
   else try pacman ....
}
```

I was thinking to something similar to autotools.. Does it exist?

Thanks and bye all :)

Comment: There might be something useful from here: http://www.rexify.org/ It's intended for remote operation, but you might be able to use just the service-related bits locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$^O`` variable will report what operating system you are on, see the document perlports platform section for how this works

perl also has a Config module that has all the information that perl worked out when it compiled - using methods similar to autotools

This example program from the man page for Config shows what information is available

```
        use Config;
       if ($Config{usethreads}) {
           print "has thread support\n"
       }

       use Config qw(myconfig config_sh config_vars config_re);

       print myconfig();

       print config_sh();


       config_vars(qw(osname archname));
```

Incidentally, puppet is great at installing packages on different platforms and varying paths for configuration.  Although it uses ruby and so may not fit in with the rest of your tool chain

Answer (score 0):

You can use chkconfig --list to find installed services.

Something like this can be done:

```
#!/bin/bash
chkmysql=`chkconfig --list | grep mysql | wc -l`
chkhttp=`chkconfig --list | grep http | wc -l`
if [[ chkmysql > 0 ]]
then
        echo "mysql is installed"
else
        echo "mysql is not installed"
        #write code to install mysql
fi
if [[ chkhttp > 0 ]]
then
        echo "http is installed"
else
        echo "http is not installed"
        #write code to install httpd service

fi
```

Comment: chkconfig isn't available on all platforms so as a solution for "help me install on different versions of Linux" it's perhaps not so great.  ISTR it is available on Redhat variants so could be good for that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not running one-off installs, I'm assuming you are in some sort of sys admin role.  Have you looked at linux kickstarts?  A kickstart allows you to get a system exactly the way you want then image it for remote install later on.  That way if a system goes down, it can be brought back up quickly with minimal external dependencies.  The problem with a self-healing method of setting up a system is it can cause more problems then it solves when it doesn't work correctly.  $0.02

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bash builtin 'type' to find out whether a given program is installed or not; or a function / an alias with the same name.

```
if ! type PROGRAM >& /dev/null; then...
```

You can parse the content of /etc/issue to get the name of the operating system.

```
if grep 'Arch Linux' /etc/issue >& /dev/null; then...
```